# Transformation in RxJS not returning the modified object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 5.1 for building an SPA that calls a couple of REST services and I'm struggling with a service response. I've defined a model to represent an *Event* and one of its fields is another object. I want to convert the object to its string representation using `JSON.stringify`. When the service call returns an array of Events, I proceed to transform that response as follows:

Consider this model:

```
export class Event {
    id: number;
    txid: string;
    eventDate: Date;
    headers: string;

    constructor(id: number,
                txid: string,
                eventDate: Date,
                headers: any) {

            this.id = id;
            this.txid = txid;
            this.eventDate = eventDate;
            this.headers = JSON.stringify(headers);

    }
}
```

And this service definition:

```
const endpoint = 'https://...';
return this
        .http
        .get<Array<Event>>(endpoint)
        .pipe(
            tap(
                elm =>
                    elm.map(e =>
                        new Event(
                            e.id,
                            e.txid,
                            e.eventDate,
                            e.headers
                        )
                    )
            ),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
```

But when I subscribe to the service, it is returning the data without the transformation, as if there's no effect.

Instead of returning `"{"header1": "value1", ...}"` it's returning an `Object`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the `tap` operator for btw?

Comment: @OsmanCea It is the new alias of `do`. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rxjs docs of [do](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do)

> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but
>   return an Observable that is identical to the source.

This means whatever you do inside of `do` won't modify your output, that's why nothing happens.

If you want to transform the source data, try using `map` instead.